# Filtering by date in jquery datable

Tags: jquery, datatables, filtering

How i can set default filtering by last date in jquery datatables?

Look like a screen:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Ejn7DmCnKMdXV1b1VmOFNNbDA/view?pref=2&pli=1

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#tableId').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 5, "desc" ]] 
    } );
```

Here 5 is order of date in table
Like 0-> id
     5-> date

Comment: its not good, i dont wanna sorting, but filtering (searching) default only by last date (23.12.2015)